# Kendo UI Window on grid button click does not open second time

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an MVC Kendo UI project and I'm having the following problem:

I have an editable kendo grid with a custom edit button which opens a partial view on a kendo window which acts like an "editor template". This seems to work fine first time but if I close the window and try to edit another item or even the same just does not work. I think that when i close the window this eliminate the element from the DOM but can't figure it out how to fix it. Here is some code:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
      .Name("gridUbicaciones")
      .Columns(col =>
          {
              col.Bound(x => x.UbicacionId);
              col.Bound(x => x.Nombre);
              col.Bound(x => x.Latitud);
              col.Bound(x => x.Longitud);
              col.Bound(x => x.Altitud);
              col.Bound(x => x.Comentario);
              col.Command(cmd =>
                  {
                      cmd.Custom("Editar").Click("editItem");                     
                      cmd.Destroy().Text("Borrar");
                  }).Width(210).HtmlAttributes(new {style = "text-align:center;"});
          })
      .ToolBar(toolbar => toolbar.Create().Text("Agregar") )
      .Pageable()
      .Sortable()
      .Filterable()
      .DataSource(dsource => dsource
                                 .Ajax()
                                 .PageSize(8)
                                 .ServerOperation(false)
                                 .Model(model => 
                                     {
                                         model.Id(x => x.UbicacionId);
                                         model.Field(x => x.UbicacionId).Editable(false);
                                     })
                                 .Read(read => read.Action("Ubicaciones_Read", "Home").Type(HttpVerbs.Post))
                                 .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Ubicaciones_Destroy", "Home"))
                                 .Update(update => update.Action("Ubicaciones_Update", "Home"))
                                 .Create(create => create.Action("Ubicaciones_Create", "Home"))
      ))
<div id="kendoWindowPopUp"></div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT :**

```
function editItem(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    if ($("#kendoWindowPopUp") == undefined)
        $("divUbicaciones").append("<div id=\"kendoWindowPopUp\"></div>");
    var windowObject = $("#kendoWindowPopUp").kendoWindow({
        resizable: false,
        modal: true,
        refresh: function () { this.center();},
        onClose: function () {

            windowObject.destroy();
            alert('hi close');// THIS CODE DOES NOT RUN
        }
       
    })
    .data("kendoWindow");
    
  

    windowObject.refresh({
        url: "/Home/EditorUbicacion?UbicacionId=" + dataItem.UbicacionId

    });
        windowObject.open();

}
```

I get the following js error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'kendoWindow'

Comment: For your edit: editItem() function is called before kendo js libraries get fetched. So maintain the order of referenced js with in a project, quick fixes may be to wrap your code within document.ready.

Comment: Thank you but still does not work wrapping my code within document.ready.

Comment: I found the solution based on what you said. I have added on my /Home/EditorUbicacion partial view another reference of jquery boundles, i just removed it and it works now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the comments. Adding it here for those like me hitting this through google :). This issue is usually caused when the page loaded via AJAX contains a script reference to jQuery. When jQuery is reinitialized, all jQuery-based data attributes are cleared, including the data(kendoWidget) attribute that holds the Kendo UI widget object.

1. Please make sure that the Window does not load a duplicate jQuery instance on the page.
2. Use 'iframe'

   ```
   $("#dialog").kendoWindow({
      // load complete page...
      content: "/foo",
      // ... and show it in an iframe
      iframe: true
   });
   ```

   You can find more at Telerik docs [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/troubleshoot/troubleshooting-common-issues#ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in your editItem(), onClose does not eliminate the element from DOM by default, you are doing it deliberately. To refresh the window content, make some checks as:

```
function editItem(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));

        // Window variable
        var wnd = $("#kendoWindowPopUp");
        if (!wnd.data("kendoWindow")) {
            // initialized on first call and successive calls will reuse this object
            wnd.kendoWindow({
                width: "600px",
                title: "title",
                actions: [
                    "refresh",
                    "Minimize",
                    "Maximize",
                    "Close"
                ],
                resizable: false,
                modal: true,
                visible: false
                // Leave all events with their default behavior                
            });
        }

        var windowObject = wnd.data("kendoWindow");
        windowObject.refresh({
            url: "/Home/EditorUbicacion?UbicacionId=" + dataItem.UbicacionId
        });
        windowObject.open().center();
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i tried your code and first time opens great but still having same error on second open: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'kendoWindow'.