# Kendo grid does not open up kendo window on button click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am working on an MVC 4 application and I have used a Kendo UI grid on my view. This view has a command column which displays button. On click of this button, I should display a kendo window (popup) which displays a partial view.On clicking 'Close' button on this window, I should once again return back to the grid and the grid should refresh.
Now I have 2 issues with this,

- Once I click the button on grid, it displays the window only
  once.i.e. if it close the window and again try to click the button on
  grid, none of the button responds!
- After I click the close button on    the window, though the window
  closes, but the grid dows not refresh.    Instead the entire page
  refreshes.

I have used the below code,

```
@(Html.Kendo()
      .Grid(Model)
      .Name("DefectGrid")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Bound(d => d.DefectId).Title("ID").Width("5%");
          columns.Bound(d => d.Title).Title("Title").Width("20%");
          columns.Bound(d => d.Severity).Title("Severity").Width("10%");
          columns.Bound(d => d.Status).Title("Status").Width("10%");
          columns.Bound(d => d.Description).Title("Description").Width("20%");
          columns.Bound(d => d.LoggedBy).Title("LoggedBy").Width("10%");
          columns.Bound(d => d.LoggedOn).Title("LoggedOn").Width("10%");
          columns.Command(command => command.Custom("ViewDetails").Click("showDetails"));
      })
      .Pageable()
      .Sortable()
      .Selectable(selectable => selectable.Mode(GridSelectionMode.Multiple))
      .Scrollable(scr => scr.Height(200))
      .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                          .Ajax()
                                          .Read(read => read.Action("LoadDefects", "Home").Data("refreshGrid").Type(HttpVerbs.Get))
                                          .PageSize(20)
                                          .ServerOperation(false)))

        @(Html.Kendo()
              .Window()
              .Name("Details")
              .Title("Defect Details")
              .Visible(false)
              .Modal(true)
              .Draggable(true)
              .Width(1000)
              .Height(600)
              .Events(ev => ev.Close("onClose"))
        )
        <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="template">
            <div id="defectDetails">
            </div>
        </script>
            function showDetails(e) {
//                e.preventDefault();

                var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
                var wnd = $("#Details").data("kendoWindow");

                var defId = dataItem.DefectId;
                var actionURL = '@Url.Action("DefectDetail", "Home")';

                wnd.refresh({
                                url: actionURL,
                                data: { defectId: defId }
                            });
                wnd.center();
                wnd.open();
            }

            function onClose(e) {
                if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to close window?"))
                    e.preventDefault();
            }
```

Can anyone suggest where I am going wrong and how can I fix the issue!!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I have resolved my first issue, thanks to the post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19837694/kendo-ui-window-on-grid-button-click-does-not-open-second-time. Please help me with the second issue

Comment: on clise button you want to refresh you grid then read this,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18399805/reloading-refreshing-kendo-grid/18399994#18399994

Comment: Still causes entire page reload. Is there somethng i need to do on the parent page where I have written @Html.Partial("...")?

Answer (score 1):

Try like this, add `script` tag and it's working fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            function showDetails(e) {

                var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
                var wnd = $("#Details").data("kendoWindow");

                var defId = dataItem.DefectId;
                var actionURL = '@Url.Action("DefectDetail", "Home")';

                wnd.refresh({
                    url: actionURL,
                    data: { defectId: defId }
                });
                wnd.center();
                wnd.open();
            }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may refresh the grid by calling `dataSource.read()` on the grid element

probably you may do in the `onClose()` event of the window,

```
$("#DefectGrid").data("kendoGrid").dataSource.read();
```

Comment: I tried the above code but it still cause entire page refresh... My grid is present inside partial view. So when I click the button in the popup, basically it should refresh only the partail view and not the entire page (ajax sort of stuff!!!). Is there something I need to do to ajaxify the partial view?